# How do I enable caching for XML data sets in Birt 2.5

Tags: caching, birt

I am building a simple BIRT report using an XML data source. However, I had to use 3 different views (3 cross-tabs) of the same data on the same report. While running the report, I noticed that BIRT was firing multiple calls to fetch the XML file (hosted in a web-server). I have tried fiddling with the settings tab of the edit screen of the data set. But the behavior does not seem to change. I would really appreciate if anybody can help me identify what is going on. Also how do I ensure that a data-set is fetched only once during the rendering of a report

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data set should only be fetched 1 time.  Do you have three data sets for the report, each one representing a different sub-set of fields?  If so that would explain the three separate fetches.

Can you create a single large data set that satisfies all the cross-tabs and then use run-time filters to produce the individual sub-sets you need?  Another option would be to consume your XML via a POJO and leverage it in the BIRT report as a scripted data set.  This would certainly give you the control you are looking for.

If you are interested in looking at building a scripted data set, have a lok here for a bit of backaground.  [accessing parameters when writing a scripted BIRT data source in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473844/accessing-parameters-when-writing-a-scripted-birt-data-source-in-java/1487920#1487920)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks!!.. I finally resorted to using a scripted datasource though it did not look like the situation needed it!...